# Google Map API is not working with StackBlitz only in Angular 6

Tags: angular, google-maps, stackblitz

I was trying to setup Google Map api for demo purpose for my students in stackblitz. I've created custom directory to show Google map.

Issue is everything works perfect into my local system. but, when I use stackblitz, I am getting `Google is not defined` error. Might be issue that I've kept googleapi.js into Index.html and it is not getting load on page. If I edit anything in code, it starts working. so, issue is only on page load.

I've tried few patches, like load map on setTimeout or load on OnInit/OnAfterViewInit. but none of them works.

Link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/googlemap-custom-directory?file=src%2Fapp%2Fgoogle-map.directive.ts

Error on Page Load:
[image]

After I Edit Soemthing:
[image]

Comment: Did you try removing the async and defer tags from the script so it will load and parse immediately?

Comment: Yes, I tried. not working still

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By placing the googleapis script in a head tag, the script loaded and parsed before the rest of the app javascript.

index.html

```
<head>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={{APIKEY}}&libraries=places"></script>
</head>
<my-app>loading</my-app>
```

Comment: ok, Its working now. I didn't know, I can add own head tag into stackblitz. it doesn't provide when we create new app. so, I thought we can't add our own.

Comment: Yeah, apparently this was a sore spot they addressed in early 2018: https://github.com/stackblitz/core/issues/188

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use setTimeout method with 1000ms inside ngAfterViewInit. Bit of hacky though.

```
setTimeout(() => {
   var mapProp = {center: new google.maps.LatLng(this.latitute, this.longitute),zoom:13,};
   console.log(mapProp);
   var map = new google.maps.Map(this.element, mapProp);
 }, 1000)
```